# tsc out creating empty outfile

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsc

I have a simple hello world file called `test.ts` with the following contents:

```
export class Hello {
  constructor() {
    console.log("hello world!");
  }
}
```

When I run the command `tsc test.ts --module amd --out bla.js`, a `test.js` file is created with the correct contents, but an empty `bla.js` file is also created.

I expected the contents of `test.ts`, and any dependencies to be compiled into `bla.js`. What is causing this behaviour?

Comment: using `--out` can hurt in the long term : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `--out` parameter tells `tsc` to

> Concatenate and emit output to single file.

...but you're defining a *module*. Modules aren't meant to be in concatenated files. So `tsc` is generating a concatenated file of all your non-module code (you have none, so `bla.js` is empty) and a module file (`test.js`) containing your `test` module.

You can prove this to yourself by adding a second `.ts` file to the command line, one that *doesn't* define a module. You'll find the transpiled version of that code in `bla.js`, and your module in `test.js`. If you add another `.ts` file that defines a second module, you'll find it in another `.js` file with the name of its source `.ts` file.

So for instance, say you have

- `Module1.ts` defining a module
- `Module2.ts` defining another module
- `Stuff.ts` defining non-module stuff
- `MoreStuff.ts` defining more non-module stuff

...and you did this:

```
tsc Module1.ts Module2.ts Stuff.ts MoreStuff.ts --out combined.js --module amd
```

You'd end up with:

- `Module1.js` containing the transpiled JavaScript for `Module1`.
- `Module2.js` containing the transpiled JavaScript for `Module2`.
- `combined.js` containing the transpiled JavaScript from `Stuff.ts` and `MoreStuff.ts`

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem. It does mean that I have to reference others with `/// <reference.../>` but that solves the problem.

Comment: @JamesMonger: ...or don't define them as modules, since you're combining everything together.

Comment: So, if we're using modules, is it possible to concatenate files into one file using `tsc` alone?  Or, must we use something like [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/)?